# MySQL select from 2 tables and replace value

Tags: mysql

There are my 2 tables: (Only the columns that interest us)

```
Table1:
   ID   |  NAME
________|_______
   0    |  null
   1    |  Fire
   2    |  Rock
Table2:
   ID   |  NAME  |  TYPE  |  TYPE2
________|________|________|_________
   1    |  El1   |   1    |    0
   2    |  El2   |   2    |    1
```

So, my table2 contains some elements, and they can have 2 types that match the id of the first table

**For example:**

- El1 is Fire only
- El2 is Rock + Fire

And I need a request that select ID, NAME, TYPE, TYPE2 but replace TYPE & TYPE2 by their NAME in the Table1.

I was looking for INNER JOIN but I don't understand how must I use it for this result...

**The result I would like is :** (for the Table2 first row)

```
$el->ID // give me 1
$el->NAME // give me El1
$el->TYPE // give me Fire
$el->TYPE2 // give me null
```

But I have no idea how to do this and it's been 2 days I'm looking for how to do :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you just need *two* inner joins here.  Each of the two joins will bring in the name from the first table, for one of the type columns in the second table.

```
SELECT
    t2.ID,
    t2.NAME,
    a.NAME,
    b.NAME
FROM Table2 t2
INNER JOIN Table1 a
    ON t2.TYPE = a.ID
INNER JOIN Table1 b
    ON t2.TYPE2 = b.ID;
```

[image]

### Demo

Comment: I could never find this alone ^^ It will help me alot, thanks!